# Error "401-Unauthorized" when consuming REST API hosted in IIS with Windows Authentication from Android device

Tags: c#, rest, maui, restsharp

Using RestSharp in .NET MAUI to develop the mobile app, I am actually trying to connect to the REST API hosted in IIS 10 with Windows Authentication (NTLM). Due to security reason, I have to use Windows Authentication. So far, the app works well in Windows machine but it is not working in Android(version 12) device. The error I am getting is "401-Unauthorized" when running it in Android device. The credentials provided are all correct.

```
        var options = new RestClientOptions("http://dev...")
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(entUser.Text, entPwd.Text, entDomain.Text)
        };
        RestClient client = new (options);
        RestRequest request = new("http://dev...", Method.Post);
        var jsonBody = new
        {
            labelSan = entLabel.Text,
            SGID = entSGID.Text,
            plant = entPlant.Text
        };
        request.AddJsonBody(jsonBody);
        request.AddHeader("apikey", entAPIKey.Text);
        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        string strResponse =  response.Content;
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", strResponse, "OK");
```

I have tried looking into the IIS log and found out that when the request is made from Windows machine, the first request from the client will be challenged by the server and the client will subsequently send the second request with the correct credentials. However, when the request is made from Android device, the client does not send the second request with the correct credential which is why I am getting the "401-Unauthorized" error.

I have been looking everywhere but to no avail. Is this a problem with the Android OS? Or is it related so some configuration in the AndroidManifest? Or is it Android OS could not work with Windows Authentication? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Windows NTLM authentication uses Kerberos to handle the challenge-response based auth flow. Refer this article on how `Kerberos` authentication can be handled in Android, https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G7WAaYEKMzj16PTHT_cIYuKXJG6bBcrQ7QQBQ6ihOcQ/edit?pli=1

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Thanks for the document but the document is more about the authentication for Chrome browser in Android. It never points out on how to do it in .NET MAUI mobile app.

Comment: Yeah, its not a direct answer. Using that as a lead you should explore more on how to get Kerberos working for a MAUI app.  Here is another [article](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/authenticate-the-net-maui-app-with-azure-ad.aspx) which is similar but it authenticates using OpenID not Kerberos.